# Facebook: people you may know

Tags: facebook

My problem/question is about people in the category "people you may know".

In this category are lot of people with one or more mutual friends. This is very clear for me. But I have there one person without any connection to me. This person know me and I know him just from the past, but we do not have any connection today and also we have not any mutual friend. Is any explanation why I see him in this category ("people you may know")? Could this happend because he is viewing my profile?? I didnt find any other reason. And he is always on my FaceBook home page and on a top position between "people you may know"!! Every other person there is connected to me through my friends.

This is happening to me a few months. So specific situation is really unlikely, is it?
Please, could you give me any explanation?

Regars,
Karla

Comment: You can get help from Facebook for user / account / site problems at https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012 - this is not the correct forum for those questions (see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  for more information)

Answer (score 0):

It also uses hometown, schools and jobs to determine that list.  Therefore, someone who grew up in your same town might be a suggested friend, even though you don't currently have any friends in common with that person.

Comment: also Facebook may use email contacts to find friends

Comment: There are lot of people from my town, there are people with 25 and more mutual friends. But this person is always on the top position.
I asked if there is any connection between profile viewing and FB friends suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that Facebook also looks at the phone numbers of people in your address book on your phone if you have installed the mobile app. I can't say this for certain, but it seems to me like it does this.

Comment: Ooooh, but I use only opera web browser on my cell phone, any Facebook application. And! This suggestion is on my FB site just ones a week or less, not everyday. Therefore it is so strange for me!

Comment: but you might have a mutual friend who uses that app, that has both of your phone numbers in their phone book even though you aren't friends on Facebook.

Comment: shit...I have hidden all of my private information, but FB see everything. Thats nice view of privacy :D THX